# Save a java source code to a file

Tags: java

sorry folks I should've elaborated more, this is my problem:

I have created a simple bean builder tool to allow users to add components like JLable or JButton or other components to a design palette and they can customize the properties of the added components as i have created the means to, now they want to save the source code of that to a file when they push a button and i want to prompt them for the name of the file, this is my problem?!?! Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question or is this one of these questions google or the documentation could answer in less than a minute?

Comment: I think my question is a bit blur what i mean is when the user changes the property of that component they push a "set" button then the changes they have made should be saved in a file like i explained...

Answer (score 2):

Use a [JFileChooser (see the example in the javadoc)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html)